# Create multiple XML2 filtering from a single XML

Tags: r, xml, xml2

With **xml2** package I want to write two XML files - one for language - starting from one XML file. For instance, I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <title xml:lang="it">Title IT</title>
    <title xml:lang="en">Title EN</title>
    <author>Author</author>
  </book>
</books>
```

and I want to save the following two files:

```
FILE IT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <title xml:lang="it">Title IT</title>
    <author>Author</author>
  </book>
</books>

FILE EN
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <title xml:lang="en">Title EN</title>
    <author>Author</author>
  </book>
</books>
```

If I do as follows:

```
txt <- "<books><book><title xml:lang='it'>Title IT</title><title xml:lang='en'>Title EN</title><author>Author</author></book></books>"
XML <- xml2::read_xml(txt)

it <- xml2::xml_find_all(XML, "//*[@xml:lang = 'it']")
en <- xml2::xml_find_all(XML, "//*[@xml:lang = 'en']")


XML_orig <- XML
xml2::xml_remove(en)
xml2::write_xml(XML, file = "book_it.xml")

XML <- XML_orig
xml2::xml_remove(it)
xml2::write_xml(XML, file = "book_en.xml")
```

when I create a copy of the `XML` object, it keeps continuing to reference to the original one. Is there a way to create a new copy without referencing? Or you know a better way to resolve the question, using the **xml2** library?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xml_remove` will remove the nodes from the document in which you found them. Swapping out the value of `XML` after you've done the find_all doesn't really help because they both still point to the original document. One way to duplicate a document seems to be the `xml_new_root` function with the `.copy=TRUE` parameter set. Here's a function that can help with your task

```
keeplang <- function(XML, lang) {
  nodepath <- paste0("//*[@xml:lang != '", lang, "']")
  filepath <- paste0("book_", lang, ".xml")
  XML <- xml_new_root(XML, .copy = TRUE)  
  nodes <- xml2::xml_find_all(XML, nodepath)
  xml2::xml_remove(nodes)
  xml2::write_xml(XML, file = filepath)
}

keeplang(XML, "it")
keeplang(XML, "en")
```

So here we make the copy, then find the nodes in that copy, then remove them. Here I changed to a `!=` comparison to only keep the values for the passed in language.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files where you pass language parameters, *en* and *it* from R to XSLT. R can run XSLT 1.0 scripts using `xslt` package (extension of `xml2`).

Specifically, you can use the same XSLT script passing values from R for the specific *title* nodes. This is not unlike passing parameters to the other well-known special-purpose language: SQL. The beauty too is XSLT is portable (again like SQL) and can be run outside R to yield same result.

**XSLT** *save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="lang" />

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="title[@xml:lang = $lang]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="author"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**R**

```
library(xml2)
library(xslt)

doc <- read_xml("Input.xml", package = "xslt")
style <- read_xml("Script.xsl", package = "xslt")

# en LANGUAGE
new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style, params=list(lang="en"))   
write_xml(new_xml, "Output_en.xml")

# it LANGUAGE
new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style, params=list(lang="it"))   
write_xml(new_xml, "Output_it.xml")
```

---

**Python** *(to demonstrate portability)*

```py
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL SCRIPT
xml = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('Script.xsl')
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)

# PASS en PARAMETER TO XSLT
n = et.XSLT.strparam("en")
result = transform(xml, lang=n)

with open("Output_en.xml", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)

# PASS it PARAMETER TO XSLT
n = et.XSLT.strparam("it")
result = transform(xml, lang=n)

with open("Output_it.xml", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**PHP**

```php
// LOAD XML AND XSLT
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
$xsl->load('Script.xsl');

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// SET en PARAMETER VALUE
$proc->setParameter('', 'lang', 'en');
$newXML = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);
file_put_contents('Output_en.xml', $newXML);

// SET en PARAMETER VALUE
$proc->setParameter('', 'lang', 'it');
$newXML = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);
file_put_contents('Output_it.xml', $newXML);
```

Comment: thanks for your effort! I'll go deep into XLST in the future, using it now in my real case might be a bit painful! But XLST looks very promising for my stuff

Comment: Understood. XSLT does take some know-how but passing param values is pretty cool. This was the first time I did it in R so thanks for question. I'm adding this to my library of solutions.